# Should I reset context from its own thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

Can I write `mainMOC.reset()` or should I nest it like here:

```
mainMOC.performBlockAndWait({

    mainMOC.reset()
})
```

I want to perform it from an arbitrary thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any calls to a context must be on the queue associated with that context.  If you are calling reset, it must be from the queue associated with the thread.  Coming from an arbitrary thread, call it in the block.

You can test this and other questions like this by turning on the concurrency debug flag.  It will let you know if you are violating the confinement constraints.

Comment: based on your context configuration I was able to make a very responsive up sync to server, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30492402/239219